# Storyshots - Cannot read property 'scrollWidth' of null

Tags: reactjs, storybook, storyshots

I want to use `renderOnly` mode for my Storyshots tests, but I am getting errors in some stories.

I can fix these errors by adding

```
createNodeMock: node => document.createElement (node.type)
```

but now I am losing `renderOnly`.

[image]